# What's the difference bewteen dynamic InfoWindows and dynamic templating in Google Fusion Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

What's the difference between 
http://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/3081246?hl=en&ref_topic=2575652 and http://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_infowindow_content?

Both of these examples seem to be trying to achieve the same thing but with different syntax, no?

Also where can I find the documentation for the syntax used in these examples? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although both examples may have the same result, they are completely different.

Dynamic templates will set the contents of the infoWindows as they will be returned by the API.
The resulting markup of dynamic templates is restricted, e.g. it's not possible to inject script-code.
The documentation for the syntax may be found at https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/concepts#expressions

Dynamic infoWindows usually ignore the `InfoWindowHtml`(the content for the infoWindow) returned by the API and override it instead based on your logic, e.g. based on values of the returned row. There is no particular syntax, it's just native javascript.
But you may also mix both, e.g. append custom HTML to the InfoWindowHtml returned by the API

In contrast to dynamic templates there are no restrictions for the contents of a dynamic infowindow

So when you must implement features that are not permitted in dynamic templates, use dynamic infoWindows, otherwise you may use any of them.

Comment: Thank you very much for that explanation, one further question if I may: Using dynamic infoWindows doesn't require me to suppress info windows from my fusion table layer? Also it doesn't require me to create markers and infowindows in the google maps api as it just overrides what is being sent by the fusion map api, right?

Comment: correct, you must only observe the click-event and set `e.infoWindowHtml` in the callback to the desired value